# grep pattern matching

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep

Following statement always returns 1 when I am expecting it to return 0:

```
 echo "ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf" | grep -e "^ACI([0-9]{9})-([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{8}).pdf$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You observed an exit of code 1, like this:

```
$ echo "ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf" | grep -e "^ACI([0-9]{9})-([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{8}).pdf$"; echo code=$?
code=1
```

To have it work as you expect, you need the -E` option:

```
$ echo "ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf" | grep -Ee "^ACI([0-9]{9})-([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{8}).pdf$"; echo code=$?
ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf
code=0
```

`-E` turns on extended regex features.

If you really want to use basic regex, which is the default, then you need to add several escapes:

```
$ echo "ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf" | grep -e "^ACI\([0-9]\{9\}\)-\([0-9]\{3\}\)-\([0-9]\{8\}\).pdf$"; echo code=$?
ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf
code=0
```

#### The meaning of `-e`

The grep option `-e` precedes a regex pattern:

```
$ echo "ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf" | grep -e '^ACI'
ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf
```

If there is only one pattern, then grep doesn't need `-e` and you can omit it:

```
$ echo "ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf" | grep '^ACI'
ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf
```

If there are two or more patterns, however, `-e` is needed:

```
$ echo "ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf" | grep -e '^ACI' -e 'pdf'
ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf
```

Comment: Thx.  Can you please explain what does "-e" do.  I did read the man description but have not understood.

Comment: OK.  I updated the answer with info on `-e`.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "ACI123456777-001-20170701.pdf"  | grep -q "ACI[0-9]\{9\}-[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{8\}.pdf"
echo $?
```